# Filling Frame with Buttons Using GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jbutton

I am trying to build a matching game with icons attached to each button. Although, this isn't close to being finished, I have a problem with filling the panel with buttons.

With this code I get a grey colored frame. If i comment out the 3 methods i use under "//execution" the panel will be all black (which is how i am testing to see if the buttons are filling the space or not.)

For some reaso,n my buttons aren't being populated onto the panel.
I need some help!!! Where am I going wrong?

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class MemoryMainFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    JButton button[] = new JButton[16];
    private static final int SIXTEEN_BUTTONS = 16;
    JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
    double dim = Math.sqrt(SIXTEEN_BUTTONS);
    int numOfColumns = (int) (dim);
    int numOfRows = (int) (dim);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MemoryMainFrame();
    }

    public MemoryMainFrame() {

        this.setTitle("MemoryGame!!!");
        this.setSize(400, 400);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setVisible(true);

        mainPanel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        mainPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        // execution
        FillButtonArray(SIXTEEN_BUTTONS);
        AddButtonListener(SIXTEEN_BUTTONS);
        ButtonToPanel(SIXTEEN_BUTTONS);

        this.add(mainPanel);
    }

    public void FillButtonArray(int numOfButtons) {
        int i = 0;

        while (i < numOfButtons) {
            button[i] = new JButton("asdf");
        }
    }

    public void AddButtonListener(int numOfButtons) {
        int i = 0;

        while (i < numOfButtons) {
            button[i].addActionListener(this);
        }
    }

    public void ButtonToPanel(int numOfButtons) {
        int n = 0;
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

        for (int i = 0; i < numOfColumns; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < numOfRows; j++) {

                gbc.gridx = i;
                gbc.gridy = j;
                n++;

                button[n].setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(
                        Color.DARK_GRAY, 2));
                mainPanel.add(button[n]);
            }
        }
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

        JFrame j = new JFrame();
        j.setSize(300, 300);
        j.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

I use the "asdf" as a test to see if the buttons work as well.

also, the actionperformed was a test as well. That part of the code is irrelevant.

Comment: `public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

        JFrame j = new JFrame();`  That suggests that the app. is using multiple frames.  See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)

Comment: "*`this.setVisible(true);
 ..  this.add(mainPanel);`"* should be "*`..this.add(mainPanel); this.pack();  this.setVisible(true);`"*.  That is likely the root of the problem.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: indeed. He also has a never-ending while loop.

Answer (score 6):

You're creating your GridBagConstraints but you're not using them.

Change this:

```
mainPanel.add(button[n]);
```

to this:

```
// passes both the component and the GBC into the container
mainPanel.add(button[n], gbc);
```

---

**Edit**
You've also got a never-ending loop here:

```
  while (i < numOfButtons) {
     button[i] = new JButton("asdf");
  }
```

and likewise for the `AddButtonListener(...)` method.

You'll want to fix this by using either a for loop or else changing `i` within the loop.

Also per Andrew Thompson's comment, you're setting the JFrame visible too early, before all components have been added.

Also your use of `Math.sqrt` then casting the result to int is very risky and risks getting unexpected results. Just declare the side length to 8 and square the int if you need to.

For an example of GridBagLayout, please check out:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")  // avoid extending JFrame if possible
public class MemoryMainPanel extends JPanel {
   private static final int ROWS = 8;
   private static final Color BACKGROUND = Color.black;
   private static final int I_GAP = 5;
   private static final Insets BTN_INSETS = new Insets(I_GAP, I_GAP, I_GAP, I_GAP);
   private JButton[][] buttons = new JButton[ROWS][ROWS];


   public MemoryMainPanel() {
      setBackground(BACKGROUND);
      setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
      for (int row = 0; row < buttons.length; row++) {
         for (int col = 0; col < buttons[row].length; col++) {
            JButton btn = new JButton(new ButtonAction(row, col));
            add(btn, createGbc(row, col));
            buttons[row][col] = btn;
         }
      }
   }

   private GridBagConstraints createGbc(int y, int x) {
      GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
      gbc.gridx = x;
      gbc.gridy = y;
      gbc.weightx = 1.0;
      gbc.weighty = 1.0;
      gbc.insets = BTN_INSETS;
      return gbc;
   }

   private class ButtonAction extends AbstractAction {
      private int row;
      private int col;

      public ButtonAction(int row, int col) {
         super("asdf");
         this.row = row;
         this.col = col;
      }

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         String text = String.format("Column, Row: [%d, %d]", col + 1, row + 1);
         Component parentComponent = MemoryMainPanel.this;
         String message = text;
         String title = "Button Pressed";
         int messageType = JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE;
         Icon icon = null;
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(parentComponent, message, title, messageType, icon);
      }
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      MemoryMainPanel mainPanel = new MemoryMainPanel();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("MemoryMainPanel");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: I have to admit. that was silly of me BUT it isn't the problem. I had been switching between GridLayout() and GridBagLayout() and was not getting either to work. I had forgotten to add in the constraints. but good catch!

Comment: Thanks! Great way to lay that out! I like how you are adding to just the contentPane().